# Valid way to delete a doc from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a game from my firestore collection, but i get error:

> TypeError: doc is not a function

I am using the latest version of Firebase. What is the proper way to delete the doc?

```
import {where,query,deleteDoc,collection, doc, getDocs, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    
deleteGame(game)  {            
  const db = getFirestore();
  const q = query(collection(db, "history"), where("date", "==", game.date));
  const doc = getDocs(q);
  const quer = await getDocs(q);

  quer.forEach((doc) => 
   {    
       deleteDoc(doc(db, "history", doc.id));
   });
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but keep in mind to `await` the `deleteDoc` call, otherwise you will have floating promises.

Comment: It depends if he want to do them sync -> if he doesn't need to wait for a response before deleting another, this way is faster. He should maybe use a catch on deleteDoc, but If he would use await, each delete would wait for the previous one (so it would be slower). Basically this depends on how the app is supposed to react if a delete fails (continue or stop execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [firebase documentation for delete data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) you should indeed use

```
deleteDoc(doc(db, "history", doc.id));
```

But doc needs to be the function imported from `firebase/firestore` . You are rewriting the value of doc with the element from quer ( *quer.forEach((**doc**) =>* ).

You also have `const doc = getDocs(q);` so you will need change the name of both `doc` variables in order to use the imported function inside the forEach callback.

Also keep in mind that this won't subcollections (if you have any - as specified in the docs).